# How to resolve Error Build when including Firebase json file

Tags: android, firebase

Unresolved dependencies

Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.0.4
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

Answer (score 1):

For Google APIs or Firebase services check whether you added the google-services plugin to your build.gradle(project) file:

```
          dependencies {
               classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
               // ...
              }
```

Then you need to add the google() repo in the top level gradle file, as specified in the firebase docs and also it should be before jcenter():

```
                buildscript {
                 repositories {
                  google()
                  jcenter()
                 }



           dependencies {
                classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
                // ...
             }
            }

           allprojects {
                repositories {
                   google()
                   jcenter()
                  }
                }
```

Add dependency for firebase-analytics

```
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add dependancy in build.gradle file as below: -

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'
```

please refer this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) for more details.